# Truncate output after X lines and print message if and only if output was truncated

Tags: text-processing, logs, output, head

Say I only need the first 5 lines of an output for logging purposes. I also need to know if and when the log has been truncated.

I am trying to use `head` to do the job, the `seq` command below outputs 20 lines that get truncated by `head`, and I `echo` a truncating information:

```
 > seq -f 'log line %.0f' 20 | head -n 5 && echo '...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines...'
log line 1
log line 2
log line 3
log line 4
log line 5
...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines...
```

But if the `seq` command outputs less than 5 lines, using the same above construction, I get a wrong "truncated" status:

```
seq -f ' log line %.0f' 3 | head -n 5 && echo '...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines...'
log line 1
log line 2
log line 3
...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines...
```

**Is there a way for the `head` command (or another tool) to tell me if it truncated anything so that I only display the "...truncated..." message when needed?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A note of warning:

When you do:

```
cmd | head
```

and if the output is truncated, that could cause `cmd` to be killed by a SIGPIPE, if it writes more lines after `head` has exited. If it's not what you want, if you want `cmd` to keep running afterwards, even if its output is discarded, you'd need to read but discard the remaining lines instead of exiting after 10 lines have been output (for instance, with `sed '1,10!d'` or `awk 'NR<=10'` instead of `head`).

So, for the two different approaches:

#### output truncated, cmd may be killed

```
cmd | awk 'NR>5 {print "TRUNCATED"; exit}; {print}'
cmd | sed  '6{s/.*/TRUNCATED/;q;}'
```

Note that the `mawk` implementation of `awk` accumulates a buffer-full of input before starting processing it, so `cmd` may not be killed until it has written a buffer-full (8KiB on my system AFAICT) of data. That can be worked-around by using the `-Winteractive` option.

Some `sed` implementations also read  one line in advance (to be able to know which is the last line when using the `$` address), so with those, `cmd` may only be killed after it has output its 7<sup>th</sup> line.

#### output truncated, the  rest discarded so cmd is not killed

```
cmd | awk 'NR<=5; NR==6{print "TRUNCATED"}'
cmd | sed '1,6!d;6s/.*/TRUNCATED/'
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use AWK:

```
seq -f 'line %.0f' 20 | awk 'NR <= 5; NR > 5 { print "...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines..."; exit }'
```

This prints the first five lines (if any) as-is; if it sees a line beyond that, it outputs the truncation message and exits.

You can specify the exit code to use, if you want to implement conditional processing:

```
seq -f 'line %.0f' 20 | awk 'NR <= 5; NR > 5 { exit 1 }' || echo ...Output truncated. Only showing first 5 lines...
```